# Conexion portable con modificacion de dll

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo una aplicación C# con conexión a una única base de datos SQLServer en mi servidor.

Ahora me solicitaron, distribuir la aplicación en al menos 20 lugares diferentes, cada lugar tiene su servidor de base de datos en local o servidor central con la misma base de datos, por ello necesito que la aplicación se pueda conectar a la base de datos con los parámetros que le pase el usuario, ip o local, usuario y password y puerto de conexión.
Vi una aplicación hecha en JAVA que mediante la modificación de una dll via interfaz de usuario en formulario, esta se adapta y conecta al servidor que le indiques justo lo que necesito, solo que esa aplicación de JAVA no es de la empresa.

En C# como puedo emplear algo parecido a lo que comento, ya sea mediante dll u otro metodo que conozcan?

Les dejo un pantallazo con lo que comento, el usuario solo modifica mediante formulario la dll y con eso la aplicacion se conecta a la base de datos sin necesidad de hacer login cada vez que accede a ella.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La cadena de conexión a una base de datos, no es más que un string que puedes cambiar al vuelo. La aplicación sólo necesita tener esto en un sitio único y almacenarlo en local, por ejemplo en un archivo de configuración.Busca en la web c# sql connection string app config, Hay infinidad de ejemplos. Si no te arreglas con el appConfig la puedes almacenar en un archivo de texto propio de la aplicación

Comment: Gracias @Javifer2 voy a investigar lo que me comentas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes jugar con la cadena de conexión, que recoja los datos de un fichero serializado y los cargue en unos textBox como los que muestras, luego cargados los datos los pasas a la cadena de conexión, recuerda que en la cadena de conexión de SQLServer el Connection Timeout se especifica en segundos no en milisegundos, por lo que si quieres establecerlo en milisegundos deberás realizar la conversión.

```
conexion = "Server=" + tbip.Text.Trim() + "," + tbport.Text.Trim() + "; Database = silestone0; User Id =" + tbuser.Text.Trim() + "; Password = " + tbpwd.Text.Trim() + "; Connection Timeout =" + int.Parse(tbtime.Text.Trim()) / 1000 + ";";
```

Comment: Este fichero que mencionas de que tipo debe ser, .txt, dll lo recomendable seria ubicarlo en el mismo directorio donde corre la aaplicaicon?
@mourazo

Comment: Si, .txt o .dat en el directorio de la aplicación